# How to implement video chat in my iphone application

Tags: iphone

I want to implement video chating features in my iphone application.

Comment: Your question as it is is too broad. Did you do any research on your own so far ? Do you need advice on which framework to use ? Do you need to use a specific protocol ? Why does your app need that, considering there are plenty of apps that do that already ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try XMPPFramework

[XMPPFramework](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/)

Comment: Thanks for fast reply.. where can i find this XMPPFramework.

Comment: @vkp: Use the link Swapna provided or use Google...

Comment: @Darkdust: this framework ask for payment. i want to free framework.

Comment: It is a free and open source project. Read the docs clearly, before adding such comments.

Comment: yes its my mistake. finally i got it.